# Spring Boot 3.1.0 Authorization Server registration endpoint always returns a login screen

Tags: spring-boot

I am attempting to access the Spring Boot 3.1.0 Authorization Server's /registration endpoint but it always returns a login screen.  The request is being sent via Postman, which has successfully accessed all the other Server auto-configured endpoints.

I am using Basic Auth for Authentication with the following body:

```
{  "redirect_uris":"https://cmdcert.greenbuttonalliance.org:8445/ThirdParty/espi/1_1/OAuthCallBack".
    "token_endpoint_auth_method":"client_secret_basic",
    "grant_types":[
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token"],
    "response_types":"code",
    "client_name":"Green Button Alliance, Inc.",
    "client_uri":"https://greenbuttonalliance.org",
    "scope":"FB=1_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_12_13_15_16_31_37_39_51_53_54_55_56_57_58_60_61_64_69;IntervalDuration=3600;BlockDuration=daily;HistoryLength=34128000",
    "contacts":"dcoffin@greenbuttonalliance.org",
    "software_id":"CMD Certification Platform EU/RC",
    "software_version":"3.3"
}
```